# Check if table does not have records then insert 3 records in table

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to Check if table does not have records then only insert 3 records in table for sql server as well as oracle.

Comment: Seems simple enough (in the same transaction, try to select a row, if none is there, insert three new ones), what have you tried, why did that not work?

Comment: Well which one is it? Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: The problem is that Oracle and SQL Server have different syntax. So you will have to have two different solutions for PL/SQL and TSQL.  Unless you can select the three rows from another table, in which case a pure SQL solution is feasible, and that can be cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of construct will work in SQL Server and Oracle:

```
SQL> insert into t34
  2  select * from emp where id <= 3
  3  and 0 in ( select count(*) from t34 )
  4  /

3 rows created.

SQL> r
  1  insert into t34
  2  select * from emp where rownum <= 3
  3* and 0 in ( select count(*) from t34 )

0 rows created.

SQL>
```

But whether it can solve your problem really depends on the source of your three rows.

Answer (score 0):

what was the problem with doing this ..

try from your part..

```
int count = select count(*) from table-name;
if(count==0){
   //your insert statements as many as
   insert into table-name values();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do something like this:

```
IF (Select count(*) from tablename) = 0
BEGIN
   -- INSERT VALUES
END
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert values in a single insert sentence you can do like this:

```
insert into yourTable (yourFields)
select value1 as yourField1, ...
where (select count(*) from yourTable ) =0
```

[Testing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/123710/):

```
create table #t (k int);

insert into #t
select 1
where (select count(*) from #t ) =0

insert into #t 
select 2 as k;

insert into #t
select 3
where (select count(*) from #t ) =0

select * from #t;
```

Notice that only '1' and '2' are inserted, not '3'.